# What are the regex capabilities of FocusWriter

Tags: regex

I am trying to remove line breaks using regex \n in FocusWriter, but it isn't recognised. Does anyone know which regex capabilities FocusWriter has? I know that [1,2,3] will match 1 or 2 or 3